# Tex code generated with R huxtable package has parts of it displayed in the output

Tags: miktex, r

I have some trouble with the generation of a standalone pdf of a table in a R script. I use huxtable R package to create a "latex" table from a regular R matrix or dataframe. Hereunder is a very simplified version of my script that reproduce the "+4pt" problem:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
library(huxtable)

age <- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66)
L2 <- factor(rep(paste(LETTERS[3:6], LETTERS[3:6], sep=""), c(1,3,2,4)))
L1 <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:2], c(4,6)))
df <- data.frame(Grp=L1, SubGrp=L2, Age=age, stringsAsFactors=F)

Stats <- df %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>% mutate(NB_Grp = n()) %>%
  group_by(SubGrp, add = TRUE) %>% mutate(NB_SubGrp = n()) %>%
  select(Grp, NB_Grp, SubGrp, NB_SubGrp, Age)

hux_tab <- as_hux(Stats, add_rownames=F, add_colnames=T)

rowspan(hux_tab)[2, 1:2] <- 4
rowspan(hux_tab)[6, 1:2] <- 6

rowspan(hux_tab)[3, 3:4] <- 3
rowspan(hux_tab)[6, 3:4] <- 2
rowspan(hux_tab)[8, 3:4] <- 4

number_format(hux_tab)[, 5] <- 0

file_name = "Tab"
tex_file <- paste(file_name,".tex",sep="")
sink(file=tex_file, append=F)
cat('\\documentclass[preview, varwidth=true]{standalone}
\\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\\usepackage{tabularx}
\\usepackage{multirow}
\\begin{document}
')
print_latex(hux_tab, tabular_only=F)
cat('\\end{document}
')
sink()


cmd <- 'pdflatex.exe -output-format=pdf ./Tab.tex'
invisible(sys(cmd))
```

With that code, I get the following tex file:

```
\documentclass[preview, varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright Grp\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright NB\_Grp\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright SubGrp\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright NB\_SubGrp\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright Age\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright CC\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright  1.00\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 62\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 60\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 63\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-4}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright A\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-4}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright  4.00\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright DD\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright  3.00\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 59\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 63\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright EE\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright  2.00\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 67\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 71\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 64\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 65\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-6}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright B\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-6}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright  6.00\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-4}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright FF\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-4}{*}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright  4.00\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace*{4pt}\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+4pt}\raggedright 66\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{4pt}\hspace*{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But the result is not as expected:

[image: Content of the PDF file]

The table has "+4pt" extra text in front of each value of the table. This seems to come from a mishandling of the "baselineskip" tex command.

The code part of the table is automaticaly generated by a function of the "huxtable" R package.

Do you see what I have to change in my R code to get the table without that "+4pt" placed everywhere ?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `\baselineskip+4pt` by `4pt`. Anyhow `\baselineskip` is zero pt where you want to use it. If not, `\dimexpr\baselineskip+4pt\relax`, but this whole code looks suspicious.

Comment: I suspect the intention is to get some minimal height, but as I said in previous comment `\baselineskip` is set to zero in such contexts.

Comment: why `tabularx` and not a single `X` column ?

Comment: never use `\begin{table}[h]`.

Comment: due to `\tabcolsep` your column specifications add for a total greater than the `.5\textwidth`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your proposals.
I don't know why the huxtable R package put such "\baselineskip+4pt" everywhere. I didn't ask it to do that.
I used a sed script to remove all the "+4pt" sequences to work-around this compiling error. It works, but I don't like this dirty solution.

Comment: It looks like it wants to ensure a minimal height above and below the text base line. This is done via a `\strut` by LaTeX already (or rather `\@arstrut`) . The definition of `\strut` could be changed temporarily, but there are more robust dedicated packages I am sure (`cellspace` comes to mind). Possibly if you add `calc` package then `\baselineskip+4pt` can be understood, but since 15 years now, `\dimexpr...\relax` gives more efficient way than `calc` package (however the LaTeX companion etc date back to antic era and e-TeX extensions are barely if at all documented)

Comment: You're right! The calc (provided by bxcalc under MikTeX Windows environment) package makes the "\baselineskip+4pt" understood by the compiler. Thanks !

Comment: well, good, but `\baselineskip` glue is set to zero dimension inside `tabularx` ! (and `tabular`...) so the code only serves for `4pt` minimal depth of the table cells but completely fails for the minimal height.

Comment: @jfbu I am the creator of the huxtable package. if you could get in touch (davidhughjones@gmail.com) and help me improve my TeX table style, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `calc` LaTeX package. To find the list of packages required by huxtable, you can use `report_latex_dependencies()` from within R, then paste them or print them to your TeX file.

Comment: Thank you, I had this same problem using huxtable (well, mine was adding "+1em" randomly to cell contents), and printing the requirements and then adding them to my overleaf fixed the issue.